# Function to track views of post only from past week

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function

I'm trying to make a function that will get the total number of views from a post ONLY from the past week.  Currently the function is getting the total number of all time views.  I basically want it to reset at 0 at the beginning of every week.  Is this possible?  How could I do this?

```js
// Popular Posts Week
function wpb_set_post_viewss($postID) {
    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_counts';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
function wpb_track_post_viewss ($post_id) {
    if ( !is_single() ) return;
    if ( empty ( $post_id) ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;    
    }
    wpb_set_post_viewss($post_id);
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpb_track_post_viewss');
```

Comment: If I were to approach this there are 2 methods I normally use. If I keep track of it myself I can just select all the views from the database in the last week with sql. The second and much easier way is to just call the google analytics api and get it that way.

Comment: @Chris, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if this is first day of the week and first view of the post and than set counter to 0.

```
function wpb_set_post_viewss($postID) {

    $currentWeekNumber = date('W');

    $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_counts';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    $weekView = get_post_meta($postID, 'weekView', true);

    if($weekView != $currentWeekNumber){
        update_post_meta($postID, 'weekView', $currentWeekNumber);
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

You can also store all views in database and get views/week with one SQL query.

Comment: When I tried adding it in my page went blank.  Would you mind posting my code with your suggestion in it?

Comment: I added my code to your function (see edited answer).

Comment: Now there are two custom fields that show up in my posts - One called weekView and it is stuck at the number 26 and one called  wpb_post_views_counts that is counting the correct number of views.  Is this working correctly?  Is wpb_post_views_counts only going to count the number of views this week and then reset next week?

Comment: If someone visit your post next week, weekView will be different from currentWeek so your counter will reset to 0.